# C: Parent and Child Processes

Tags: c, process, fork, parent, child-process

I'm attempting to do the following...

```
Create a new process
obtain the PID of a process
put a process to sleep for a defined period of time
check process ID on the terminal
```

My program runs, but the output is not what I'd expect it to be and I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!

Code:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    pid_t pid=0;

    /** use fork() system call to create a new process */
    /** if the pid returned by fork() is negative, it indicates an error */

    if(fork()<0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid==0) {
        printf("child PID= %d\n", (int) getpid());
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("child: %d\n", i);
            /** put process to sleep for 1 sec */
            sleep(1);
        }
    } else {
        /* parent */
        /** print the parent PID */
        printf("parent PID= %d\n", (int) getpid());
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("parent: %d\n", i);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

The output is supposed to look something like...

```
parent PID=8900
child PID=4320
parent:0
child:0
child:1
parent:1
child:2
parent:2
child:3
parent:3
parent:4
etc.
```

But i'm getting...

```
child PID= 97704
child: 0
child PID= 106388
child: 0
child: 1
child: 1
child: 2
child: 2
child: 3
child: 3
child: 4
child: 4
child: 5
child: 5
child: 6
child: 6
child: 7
child: 7
```

Comment: `if ( fork() < 0 )` --> `if ( (pid=fork()) < 0 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated above, you're not assigning `pid` to anything, so it's always zero.  You should also change your condition to be `pid` instead of calling another `fork()`.

```
int main() {
int i;
pid_t pid=0;

pid = fork(); /* Add this */

/** use fork() system call to create a new process */
/** if the pid returned by fork() is negative, it indicates an error */

if(pid<0) { /* Change this */
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}
```

Also, don't be surprised if your expected output still looks different than what you're expecting.  There is no way to tell when the child or parent will be called (especially if you took out the sleep).  It depends on a variety of things.

EDIT: I see what you're saying.  You want to check the process ID via the terminal?  You could add a `getchar();` to the end of your program to pause the program from exiting then you could open another terminal and run `ps`.  You need to make sure you add `#include <stdio.h>`, to use it though.

Comment: Awww okay okay, I see now. How would I go about checking the process ID? I've been told that typing ps while executing will show it, but so far ps doesn't execute until the program is done running

Comment: I am slightly confused.  `ps` is a shell command that reports the information about the current processes.  To check the process id, just check the value of pid, like you were doing.

Comment: @Bob see my edit above.  That's one way you could get the process ID of the program from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really assign the output of fork() to pid, so pid stays at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pid` for comparisons instead of calling another `fork()`. Set `pid` equal to `fork()` so you can compare it to check for errors in the `pid`.

```
int main() {
    int i;
    pid_t pid=0;
    pid = fork();

    /** use fork() system call to create a new process */
    /** if the pid returned by fork() is negative, it indicates an error */

    if(pid<0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid==0) {
        printf("child PID= %d\n", (int) getpid());
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("child: %d\n", i);
           /** put process to sleep for 1 sec */
            sleep(1);
        }
    } else {
       /* parent */
        /** print the parent PID */
        printf("parent PID= %d\n", (int) getpid());
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("parent: %d\n", i);
            sleep(1);
       }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/help and try to reformulate your question so others can help you better.